# Регулярное выражение лишние символы

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть задача, написать регулярное выражение на пропуск 2х слов, к примеру имя и фамилия, на любом языке (англ, немецкий...).

Вот как я подумал

```
    var str = "Имя фамилия текст текст";
    str.match(/^[^!@#]+ [^!@#]+$/i);
```

И вот результат

```
["Имя фамилия текст текст"]
```

Почему , регулярное выражение прошло валидацию? МОжет я не правильно проверяю, я не пойму...

По идее, регулярка должна найти совпадение

**начало_строки**[любой_символ_кроме!@#]минимум1раз **пробел**  [любой_символ_кроме!@#]**конец_строки**

Но, в примере после 2ого слова есть еще пробелы, символы, и их тоже пропускает

Мне нужно проверить на любые символы кроме тех 3х знаков

Вот тестер
https://regex101.com/r/kJ5vZ2/4

Comment: даже если вы вот так оставите `^[^!@#]+$` тоже пройдет :) у вас пробел  не входит в запрещенные знаки, добавьте его в скобочки им заработает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы сами отвечаете на свой вопрос. Регулярное выражение `[^!@#]+` включает в себя любые символы кроме **!**, **@** и **#** в том числе включает и *пробел*! А это значит, что вся строка `Имя фамилия текст текст` подходит под первое `[^!@#]+`. Добавьте в список исключаемых слов **пробел**.

Пример:

```
var str = "Имя фамилия текст текст";
str.match(/^[^!@# ]+ [^!@# ]+$/i);
```

https://regex101.com/r/kJ5vZ2/5